# Why does the `man` command not handle SIGINT or SIGQUIT?

Tags: man, signals

When using `man`, I noticed that you need to use the `q` key to exit instead of using `CTRL + C` (SIGINT) or `CTRL + D` (SIGQUIT) signals. Is there any reason for this? I couldn't find anything in the man pages *for* man about it.

Comment: `man` uses a pager which may be e.g. `less`. If it's `less` in your case then the question is really about `less`, I think.

Comment: thanks! found a [relevant question](https://superuser.com/questions/60328/what-is-the-interrupt-key-for-linux-command-less) -- unless this subquestion falls under the duplication guidelines, feel free to transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: Also when you use `Ctrl` + `D` in `less` this is a shortcut for: [forward half window](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/)

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer. If anyone wants to answer then go ahead. You won't be stealing my thunder or anything.

Answer (score 0):

`man`'s underlying pager is `less`, which handles [kill codes](https://superuser.com/questions/60328/what-is-the-interrupt-key-for-linux-command-less) differently.

To summarize:

- `CTRL + D` doesn't work because it's a shortcut for [forward half window](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/)
- `CTRL + C` doesn't work unless you pass the [`--quit-on-intr`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/less/less.1.en.html) flag.